# "ShowDialog / DialogResult" alternative in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

In WPF I often used such a construction:

```
SomeChildWindow dlg = new SomeChildWindow();
dlg.ShowDialog();
...
//child window is closed either by "this.DialogResult = true;" or just by "Close();"    
//and in Parent window after Child window is closed we can use condition based on that
...

   if (dlg.DialogResult == true)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

But in Silverlight this approach doesn't work.

What is the alternative in Silverlight for this? I mean how it is supposed to get a feedback from the child window in Silverlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't support fully-modal dialogs, which prevents the traditional approach for checking dialog results. Instead, you need to assign an event handler to the dialog that will process the dialog result. The event is [`ChildWindow.Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow.closed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

You can then obtain [`ChildWindow.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow.dialogresult%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in that event handler to handle it accordingly.

```
private void OnDialogClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   var window = (ChildWindow)sender;
   if (window.DialogResult ?? false)
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. it works. But when dropping "==true" as you suggested I get an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @rem: Totally forgot that the result is a nullable. Sorry about that. I personally would use `window.DialogResult ?? false`, rather than `window.DialogResult == true`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by handling the close event:

```
SomeChildWindow dlg = new SomeChildWindow();

dlg.Closed += (s, eargs) =>
{
   if(dlg.DialogResult == true)
   {
      //do something
   }
};

dlg.Show();
```